# Gitlab CI job fails even if the script/command is successful

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a CI stage with the following command, which has to be executed remotely and checks if the mentioned file exists, if yes it creates a backup for it.

```
  script: |
    ssh ${USER}@${HOST} '([ -f "${PATH}/test_1.txt" ] && cp -v "${PATH}/test_1.txt" ${PATH}/test_1_$CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP.txt)'
```

The issue is, this job always fails whether the file exists or not with the following output:

```
ssh user@hostname '([ -f /etc/file/path/test_1.txt ] && cp -v /etc/file/path/test_1.txt /etc/file/path/test_1_$CI_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP.txt)'
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Running the same command manually, just works fine. So,

How can I make sure that this job succeeds as long as command logic is executed successfully and only fail incase there are some genuine failures?

Comment: Ever tried calling `exit` remotely, in order to explicitly close the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for the job to know if the command you ran remotely worked or not. It can only know if the ssh instruction worked or not. You can force it to always succeed by appending  `|| true` to any instruction.

However, if you want to see and save the output of your remote instruction, you can do something like this:

`ssh user@host command 2>&1 | tee ssh-session.log`